# Devise customisation with CSS and Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i am using devise with my current app and I have customised the css so the flash alerts/notices appear in a box i created with css.

What i would like to do is have the option to close the div box by clicking an x in the top right hand corner. Ive done some reading and can see that this is achievable with Jquery, however my jquery skills are at novice level at present..

Has anyone done this within a rails app using devise?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put together a simple 'close' function using jquery.

Try this. I think its what you are after.

http://jsfiddle.net/ollie/FNXVX/1/

Comment: Hi, I have put your code into my app ( Many thanks for showing me hoq), I have a further query though as my notices are triggered by devise which means i have this in my application layout

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you are asking. Is devise some sort of api?

Comment: sorry got half way through and didn't delete. I have created a new question titled "modify devise alerts (Rails 3")  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285948/modify-devise-alerts-rails-3, would you be able to look at that? thanks

Comment: devise is an authentication gem for user login